# C# WPF Trigger textbox update from code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, triggers

I have this textbox:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="StatusTextBlock" Foreground="Black">
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:4" >
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                  Storyboard.TargetName="StatusTextBlock"
                                  AutoReverse="False">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Black"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Black"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Black"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
```

Now in my codebehind i want to trigger an update inside a method:

```
public void UpdateStatusBlock(string text)
    {
        StatusTextBlock.Text = text;
        // How can i trigger the animation in here
    }
```

How can i trigger the animation ?

Comment: Here's a good article on triggering animations from code behind: http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work you have to bind the TextBlox.Text property to some object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Why? Because you the defined trigger that fires only when "Binding.TargetUpdated".

Here how it looks like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new SampleViewModel();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SampleViewModel vm = (SampleViewModel) this.DataContext;
            vm.SampleText = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        }
    }

public class SampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _sampleText;

        public string SampleText
        {
            get { return _sampleText; }
            set
            {
                _sampleText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

and finally you have to bind the Text property to the "SampleText" property of your view model.

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="StatusTextBlock" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding SampleText,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
```

Note that NotifyOnTargetUpdated has to be defined also, because It indicates whether to raise the TargetUpdated event or not.